# Codeigniter and SQL/Haversine Formula

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, haversine

I am using Codeigniter for a project and have some locations with latitude and longitude inputs on the database. I'm trying to get points within a certain distance (50km), and attempting it with the Haversine Formula. However, on my controller and view it doesn't print out the results. What I need to know is if there's any adjustments I need to make to get the model function working.

Note: The DB table has the column names location_latitude and location_longitude.

```
//base function to compare distance with
$setlat = 13.5234412; 
$setlong = 144.8320897; 
//query with Haversin formula 
$awaka = "SELECT 'location_id',
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians('location_latitude') ) * cos( radians('location_longitude') - radians(?) )
    + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians('location_latitude') ) ) ) AS 'distance'
    FROM 'locations' HAVING 'distance < 5'";
 $result = $this->db->query($awaka, array($setlat, $setlong, $setlat));  
 echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you got a little tripped up by the Haversine formula.  You switched the `$setlong` and `location_longitude` terms in the third `cosine` term.  I switched them around to get this:

```
$setlat = 13.5234412; 
$setlong = 144.8320897; 
$awaka = "SELECT 'location_id',
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians('location_latitude') ) * cos( radians(?) - radians('location_longitude') )
    + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians('location_latitude') ) ) ) AS 'distance'
    FROM 'locations' HAVING 'distance < 5'";
$result = $this->db->query($awaka, array($setlat, $setlong, $setlat));  
echo $result;
```

Have a look at [this page](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/), which shows you have to code up the Haversine formula to find the distance between two points.

Comment: This worked after a few tweaks. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is an Active Records that help you it works for me.

```
$this->db->select("location_id,round((6371 * acos(cos(radians($setlat)) * cos(radians(location_latitude)) * cos(radians('$setlong') - radians(location_longitude)) + sin(radians('$setlat')) * sin(radians(location_latitude)))),2) AS distance", false);
$this->db->having('distance < 5', false);
$data = $this->db->get('locations')->result_array();
return $data;
```

Comment: I have a white screen. Nothing showing, will tweak with the controller.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

Comment: Are you using active records or simple query

Comment: I'm using active records.

Comment: Instead of `result_array()` try only `result()`

Comment: I still got the same result.