# How can i fetch hotels that are stored in a database which are near a given latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a table where I have stored latitude,longitude and location of hotels. The feature I would like to implement should display hotels taken from database which are near the given point defined by latitude and longitude.

**Controller**

```
       function check()
       {
        $this->load->model('hotel');  
        $lat1=$this->input->post('lat');
        $lng1=$this->input->post('lng');
        $count['matched_data'] = $this->hotel->hoteldisplay($lat1,$lng1);
        $checkdb =count( $count['matched_data']);
        }
   Here is model:
            function hoteldisplay($lat1,$lng1)
           {
           $this->db->select("landmark,(3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat1) ) * 
           cos( radians(lat) ) * cos( radians(longi) - rad`ians($lng1)+sin( 
           radians($lat1) ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) ) AS distance");  
           $this->db->having('distance' <= 25);                     
           $this->db->order_by('distance');                    
           $this->db->limit(20, 0);
           }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What is your question? What is the framework you're using?

Comment: think he is using codeigniter based on the  format @YazanWYusuf ....but im guessing his controller models are correct he wants to create a client side ajax event function  for the marker .. that when the marker is pinned it should post the lat and long and return the response and update the map

Comment: yes i am using codeigniter. and my question is what query to should i use to fetch data from database based of latitude and longitude.like for example:if marker on google map is pointed at latitude=15.3068003 and longitude=78.45672230000002 then it should fetch all the data that has latitude and longitude near to pointed latitude and longitude.

Comment: yes i have used ajax function for marker and it is working correctly.but the problem is with query.wherever marker is pointed on google map it shows count 0 even though there are many entries saved in database. pls do suggest me with a proper query it will be helpful.

Comment: view (ajax function): google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            var location = e.latLng;
            var l1=location.lat();
            var l2=location.lng();
              $.ajax({
                   type:"POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/map_c/mapcheck",
                    data:{ lat:l1,lng:l2},
                    success: function(mapdb){
                    var c=JSON.parse(mapdb);
                    alert(c);
                     addMarker(e.latLng,mapdb);
                   }
               });  
       });

Comment: Made the question more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to apply the Haversine distance in your SQL query. This is an example:

```
 SELECT z.zip,
        z.primary_city,
        z.latitude, z.longitude,
        p.distance_unit
                 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                 * COS(RADIANS(z.latitude))
                 * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint) - RADIANS(z.longitude))
                 + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(z.latitude)))) AS distance_in_km
  FROM zip AS z
  JOIN (   /* these are the query parameters */
        SELECT  42.81  AS latpoint,  -70.81 AS longpoint,
                50.0 AS radius,      111.045 AS distance_unit
    ) AS p ON 1=1
  WHERE z.latitude
     BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
         AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
    AND z.longitude
     BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
         AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
  ORDER BY distance_in_km
LIMIT 15
```

Taken from [here](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/). As about Code Igniter, you can apply this there as well, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366466/codeigniter-and-sql-haversine-formula).